# Activerecord-import getting ArgumentError: Invalid arguments! error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, activerecord-import

I am trying to import with activerecord import. I am getting Invalid arguments error how can I fix this?

Thanks

My table schema in postgresql:

```
create_table "vehicle_locations", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string "plate"
t.datetime "timestamp"
t.float "latitude"
t.float "longitude"
t.integer "speed"
t.integer "mileage"
t.boolean "ignition_on"
t.string "address"
end
```

and I am trying to import with following code:

```
values = [{"plate":"xxx","timestamp":"2017-11-28 
 20:42:57","latitude":41.9322,"longitude":27.3253,"speed":0,"mileage":1984
 04,"ignition_on":true,"address":"address"},{"plate":"xxx","timestamp":"2017-11-28 20:43:46","latitude":47.0148,"longitude":39.1805,"speed":16,"mileage":209726,"ignition_on":true,"address":"address"}]

   columns = [:plate, :timestamp, :latitude, :longitude, :speed, :mileage, :ignition_on,  :address ]
  VehicleLocation.import columns, values
```

I am using postgresql, rails 5.1.

Thanks in advance.

```
 2017-11-28T17:45:08.844Z 17976 TID-gn4tnwlkc WARN: ArgumentError: Invalid arguments!
2017-11-28T17:45:08.844Z 17976 TID-gn4tnwlkc WARN: /home/kayayan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-import-0.21.0/lib/activerecord-import/import.rb:508:in `import_helper'
/home/kayayan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-import-0.21.0/lib/activerecord-import/import.rb:399:in `import'
/home/kayayan/Projects/RoR/trasportapp/app/workers/trio_worker.rb:23:in `perform'
/home/kayayan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sidekiq-5.0.5/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:188:in `execute_job'
/home/kayayan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sidekiq-5.0.5/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:170:in `block (2 levels) in process'
/home/kayayan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sidekiq-5.0.5/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:128:in `block in invoke'
/home/kayayan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sidekiq-5.0.5/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:133:in `invoke'
/home/kayayan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sidekiq-5.0.5/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:169:in `block in process'
/home/kayayan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sidekiq-5.0.5/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:141:in `block (6 levels) in dispatch'
/home/kayayan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sidekiq-5.0.5/lib/sidekiq/job_retry.rb:97:in `local'
/home/kayayan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sidekiq-5.0.5/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:140:in `block (5 levels) in dispatch'
/home/kayayan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sidekiq-5.0.5/lib/sidekiq/rails.rb:42:in `block in call'
/home/kayayan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:85:in `wrap'
/home/kayayan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/reloader.rb:68:in `block in wrap'
/home/kayayan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:85:in `wrap'
/home/kayayan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/reloader.rb:67:in `wrap'
/home/kayayan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sidekiq-5.0.5/lib/sidekiq/rails.rb:41:in `call'
/home/kayayan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sidekiq-5.0.5/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:136:in `block (4 levels) in dispatch'
/home/kayayan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sidekiq-5.0.5/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:204:in `stats'
/home/kayayan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sidekiq-5.0.5/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:131:in `block (3 levels) in dispatch'
/home/kayayan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sidekiq-5.0.5/lib/sidekiq/job_logger.rb:7:in `call'
/home/kayayan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sidekiq-5.0.5/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:130:in `block (2 levels) in dispatch'
/home/kayayan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sidekiq-5.0.5/lib/sidekiq/job_retry.rb:72:in `global'
/home/kayayan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sidekiq-5.0.5/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:129:in `block in dispatch'
/home/kayayan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sidekiq-5.0.5/lib/sidekiq/logging.rb:44:in `with_context'
/home/kayayan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sidekiq-5.0.5/lib/sidekiq/logging.rb:38:in `with_job_hash_context'
/home/kayayan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sidekiq-5.0.5/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:128:in `dispatch'
/home/kayayan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sidekiq-5.0.5/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:168:in `process'
/home/kayayan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sidekiq-5.0.5/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:85:in `process_one'
/home/kayayan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sidekiq-5.0.5/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:73:in `run'
/home/kayayan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sidekiq-5.0.5/lib/sidekiq/util.rb:16:in `watchdog'
/home/kayayan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sidekiq-5.0.5/lib/sidekiq/util.rb:25:in `block in safe_thread'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [Documentation for ActiveRecord Import](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import/wiki/Examples#import-using-columns-and-arrays), the method you are using takes an array of columns as the first argument (which you have) and the second argument is an array of arrays, where each array has the values you want to insert.

Your `values` variable is an array of hashes, so you'll need to convert it like so

```
values = values.map(&:values)
puts values
#=> [["xxx", "2017-11-28 20:42:57", 41.9322, 27.3253, 0, 198404, true, "address"], ["xxx", "2017-11-28 20:43:46", 47.0148, 39.1805, 16, 209726, true, "address"]]
```

For each hash in `values` we call [Hash#values](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Hash.html#method-i-values) - which returns a new array of just the values in the hash.

Or, just use [this version of #import](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import/wiki/Examples#import-using-hashes) which takes a hash.

```
values = [{"plate":"xxx","timestamp":"2017-11-28 
 20:42:57","latitude":41.9322,"longitude":27.3253,"speed":0,"mileage":1984
 04,"ignition_on":true,"address":"address"},{"plate":"xxx","timestamp":"2017-11-28 20:43:46","latitude":47.0148,"longitude":39.1805,"speed":16,"mileage":209726,"ignition_on":true,"address":"address"}]

VehicleLocation.import values
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to modify your code as follows:

```
locations = values.map do |attrs|
  VehicleLocation.new(attrs)
end

VehicleLocation.import(locations)
```

As shown in [the docs](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import/wiki/Examples#import-using-activerecord-models)